# Probability of a number of people going wrong in a given sample

Tags: probability

In a sample of 100 people how many people will answer a question incorrectly when the probability of each one of them answering a question correctly is 0.98?

I wrote the following python program to simulate this:

```
    import random

    def single_person():
    # returns True for 98 out of 100 times.
     i = random.randint(1, 100)
     if i <= 2:
       return False
     else:
       return True  

    def multiple_persons( sample):
     """countF is count of favourable outcome i.e. True 
        and countUnF is the count of unfavourable outcome 
        i.e. False"""
     countF = 0
     countUnF = 0
     for i in range(0, sample):
       if single_person():
         countF += 1
       else:
         countUnF += 1
     return (countUnF/ sample)
```

Using the program I never get a probability of 0.02. but close to it, I even get a probability of 0.16.

The answer to this question  is 2 but why can't more people go wrong?

Comment: The range for the loop shouldn't be (1,sample) ? Also, try making the mean of the probability after multiple tries (at least 10). The more tries you make, the more that mean will get closer to 0.02.

Comment: The expected value of the number of incorrect answers is 2, but this is an _expected_ value, not an absolute; it can vary when repeating the experiment.

Comment: The loop goes from 0 to sample-1 values and therefore, iterating sample times. And if I keep the sample value to be more than 100,000 I get close to 0.02

Comment: You've unintentionally discovered the Law of Large Numbers. Essentially, when your sample size is low (let's say you run the experiment with ten people), you might get nine correct and one incorrect, resulting in an incorrect percentage of 10% which is way off from 2%. But as you increase the sample size, you notice that the incorrect percentage seems to "converge" to 2%. DylanSp is right in saying 2 is the expected value - you'll get trials of 1 or 3 incorrect, and if you're unlucky, you might get a trial where all 100 are incorrect! But with a larger sample size, you can feel more confident.

Comment: Does that mean that even after calculating the probability everything is uncertain?